# Father class as parameter and implement its derivates classes C# MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, inheritance, abstract-class

I'm really new in the MVC pattern and I would like to do an implementation like this:

```
public ActionResult Create(PersonModel p)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            switch (p.PersonType)
            {
                case PersonType.Client:

                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                case PersonType.Employee:
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                case PersonType.Lawyer:

                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                    //return RedirectToAction("Create", "Lawyer",p);
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.CourtBranches = new SelectList(courtBranch.GetAllCourtBranches(), "ID", "Name");
            return View(person);
        }
    }
```

But the problem starts when I want to use the classes that inherits from "PersonModel"(an abstract class) in my PersonsController, because VisualStudio understands that there's a PersonModel and not other classes. How can I "lie" to VS? In my db I've a one-on-one relationship between the Persons and each one of its inheritances.

It's important to know that I've a method that instances the selected Person in the View through receiving the "PersonType" from the POST, and it works. So when I run the project, I recive a Lawyer, an Employee or a Client.

Is a possibility using something like `return RedirectToAction("Create", "Lawyer",p);`? But just not showing anything in the view, "accessing directly to the POST" if I can make my idea understand.

Well, thanks to everyone who reads all of this post. Gonna appreciate every answer :)

Comment: Its unclear what your trying to do here. You have shown a `Create()` method (I assume its marked with `[HttpPost]` and saves a item in the database) so why are you wantig to then redirect to another `Create()` method?

Comment: Hi @StephenMuecke . My idea was to receive any `PersonModel` inheritance in the `Create()`, and then, as you said, save it into a db. But the problem is that I want to use the same View, just using the style `display:none` and handling which html show by a script. Is it possible or the only way is using several views? Thanks for your help.

Comment: _just using the_ what?

Comment: Sorry about my english @StephenMuecke. I've this script: `$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#PersonType').change(function () {
        selection = $(this).val();
        switch (selection) {
            case 'Lawyer':
                $('#Lawyer').show();
                $('#Employee').hide();
                $('#Client').hide();
                break; //and the others...
` and when a `select` tag changes, it changes the html display. Then when I POST, I instanciate a Lawyer/Employee/Client depdending the select with a method that inherits from `DefaultModelBinder`

Comment: Not only is it crazy to be generating 3 separate lots of html in the view, the code can never work anyway - the model in your parameter is `PersonModel` so only the properties of `PersonModel` will ever be bound (any specific properties of `Laywer` or `Client` etc will be ignored unless you have a custom ModelBinder

Comment: You need 3 different POST methods. And in the initial view just render the `<select>` Then handle its `.change()` event and use ajax to call a server method that returns a partial view of a form for a Lawyer or Client depending on the selection (which will post back to the corresponding POST method)

Comment: I've got the custom ModelBinder, when I run the project I receive the correct instance and all the values of the properties that I posted. That's why I'm trying to do this. So then, it isn't correct? Should I've to do this by showing partialViews for each Person type? Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks!!! I've never used ajax but I'll try anyway. Really appreaciate your help. I can't give any points because I'm really new, but I really thank you!

Comment: Your just degrading performance by generating 3 times as much html as you need and sending all to the client. Just load it as needed. If you do have a custom ModelBinder, then having the one POST method is probably OK, but its not clear then why your trying to do `return RedirectToAction("Create", "Lawyer",p);`

Comment: @StephenMuecke `return RedirectToAction("Create", "Lawyer", p)` was a bad idea that I tried. Just ignore it. I send all the html because there aren't much properties to add for each inheritance. Are you saying me that I can use only one POST method? How can I "say" to visualstudio that the parameter will be an inheritance of PersonModel?

Comment: But you have just said you have a custom `ModelBinder` that creates the model as `Lawyer` or `Client` etc. and binds their properties. So you just need to cast it - `case PersonType.Client: Client client = p as Client;`

Comment: IT WORKS!!! THANKS MAN! Incredibly, one line with an "as" did it work perfectly. I Really thank you @StephenMuecke

Answer (score 0):

Why not using several actions like :

```
public ActionResult CreateEmployee(EmployeeModel model)
{
   // ...
}

public ActionResult CreateLawyer(LawyerModel model)
{
   // ...
}
```

In any view when you want to display a Person:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m)
```

And in Views\Shared\DisplayTemplates\EmployeeModel.cshtml

```
@model EmployeeModel
@* specific layout for Employee *@
```

Views\Shared\DisplayTemplates\LawyerModel.cshtml

```
@model LawyerModel
@* specific layout for Lawyer *@
```

Comment: Hi Toine, thanks for your answer. I wan't to do it in this way because in my View of PersonModel I've a script that shows the selected person html when a <select> tag changes.

Comment: According to your answer, how can I do it? I didn't understood how to get inside of the "Views\Shared\DisplayTemplates\LawyerModel.cshtml" from de PersonView.  Maybe a @RenderBody or a @RenderPartialView? How can I route to a specify controller from my .html?(e.g. if "Lawyer" is chosen, route the app to CreateLawyer). It can be a useful way I think. Thanks again for answering me!

Comment: Seperate the 3 creation processes as you would do for 3 types differents.

Then if you want to display somewhere a PersonModel in your app, just use @Html.DisplayFor(model => model). It will automatically display the DisplayTemplate associated to the type of your model.

Comment: http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_asp/mvc/using-display-templates-and-editor-templates-in-asp.net-mvc.htm

Comment: Thanks @ToineSeiter !! That's a good way to do it. I didn't know about that html helper. Thanks!!

Comment: Could you accept the answer if it suit you please ? :)